# Why is my span moving down when I add additional text?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project that involves a span of text. The span is added to by javascript, for example if I add 'a' to the span, the formatting is fine, but if I add a second character, 'b', both characters and all characters written after that move down about a few pixels, and stay at that line. The span must always display text in the same place, I'm using a monotype font so there's uniform display. I thought maybe the span was wordwrapping or something. Strangely, I've used this same span and code on my Wordpress site with no issues. It's just the standalone html, javascript, and CSS that are having the issue. My current CSS for the span looks like this. I also tried copying the CSS profile from Wordpress but didn't see anything obvious that would be changing where the text position after adding a second character.

```
#dlpasscode {
display:block;
z-index: 2;
width: 170px;
top: 144px;
left: 120px;
font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono';
font-size: 28px;
color: white;
margin-top:0;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 28px;
vertical-align: baseline;    
white-space:nowrap;    
overflow: hidden;}
```

The javascript I'm calling to display the characters (this is for a UI simulator and each ID is passed in as a character then added to the string).

```
    function dlDisplayPass(lastOptScreen) {
        switch (lastOptScreen) {
            case dlSim.enterNewPass.src:
            case dlSim.confNewPass.src:
                passStore = passStore + clicked.id;
                jQuery('#dlpasscode').append(clicked.id);
                break;
            default:
                // display up to 9 masked characters, stop and need to display arrow
                // allows only up to 32 characters, ignores clicks after that and beeps
                if (passStore.length < 32) {
                    passStore = passStore + clicked.id;
                } else {
                    longbeep.playclip();
                }

                var passArray = null;

                if (passStore.length <= 8) {
                    passArray = new Array(passStore.length).join(dlpassmask);
                }
                if (passStore.length === 9) {
                    passArray = new Array(9).join(dlpassmask);
                }
                if (passStore.length >= 10 && passStore.length < 32) {
                    passArray = leftArrow + new Array(8).join(dlpassmask);
                }
                if (passStore.length < 32) {
                    jQuery('#dlpasscode').text(passArray).append(clicked.id);
                }


        }
        return false;
    }
```

The actual span just looks like this

```
<span class="dlbezel dlchild" id="dlpasscode" unselectable ></span>
```

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: Sorry, new to StackExchange, just a second.

Comment: I've not used `text().append()` in that way before. What does the markup look like after? I'm wondering whether additional DOM elements are being appended.

Comment: I'm thinking you might be right. I've been messing with it and Chrome is displaying the append like this. "●" "0" , rather than as a single span of text. `<span class="dlbezel dlchild" id="dlpasscode" unselectable="">0</span>` for the first click, then second click looks like `<span class="dlbezel dlchild" id="dlpasscode" unselectable="">●0</span>`

Comment: I separated the two commands out to ` jQuery('#dlpasscode').text(passArray);
                        jQuery('#dlpasscode').append(clicked.id);` and commented out the .text function, and the problem has gone away. Somehow .text is what's changing it, not the .append. According to jQuery, Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out updating jQuery updated the issue. Per their website, [the jQuery().text() function](http://api.jquery.com/text/) says "due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space."

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Turns out I'm wrong. The issue is cropping up in Chrome, with the .text() on jQuery, and doesn't manifest in Safari. I'll keep looking trying to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Apparently it was a simple font issue, in attempting to use Ubuntu Mono there was an issue. Using Sans Serif corrects the issue and the characters don't move slightly on the screen when additional characters are added.